# Apache JMeter - SSL Handshake error

Tags: apache, jmeter

Couple of performance scripts are failing because of the SSL Handshake error and the error message we get is

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
Response message: Non HTTP response message : Received fatal alert handshake failure
```

What are the reasons for it?

**UPDATE**:
I ran this test from two machines

On one machine it got passed
On another machine it got failed due to handshake problem

And this issue occurs when HSTS is set to true in the certificate!

Comment: Give mire details. Do you use F5? Firewall? ..

Comment: What are your JMeter and JDK version?

Comment: yes we do use F5 and it works with one website  but not the other one

Comment: @Jahan JDK is 1.8.0_152 and JMeter version is 3.2

Comment: Is this issue occurs with Jmeter 4.0? Could you check?

Comment: Please see my updated comments..Even with JMeter 4.0 its the same issue

Answer (score 1):

If you have one machine where everything works fine and another one where you see errors the most straightforward solution would be just copying over JMeter from the "good" machine to the "bad" one.

If it doesn't help - do the same for your [JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) (or [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit))

You can also try getting to the bottom of the issue and identify the root cause. The first thing you should do is to check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries. If there is nothing connected with the error there - increase log verbosity by uncommenting the next lines in *log4j2.xml* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder):

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.util.HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory" level="debug" />
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager" level="debug" />
```

See [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) article to learn more about troubleshooting JMeter issues via log files manipulation.

Don't forget to revert the changes once you determine and fix your problem as excessive logging causes massive disk IO and might ruin your test.